# Numpy array: assignment of value fails

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this code snippet:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([5,6,7,8,9])
b=np.array([5,6,7,8,9])

scoreA = np.array([float(1) / (i + 1) for i in range(len(a))])
scoreB = np.array([0 for i in range(len(b))])

for eleA in a:
    if eleA in b:
        i, = np.where(b == eleA)
        i = i[0]
        j, = np.where(a == eleA)
        j = j[0]
        scoreB[i] = scoreA[j]

        print "B is: %f" % scoreB[i]
        print "A is: %f" % scoreA[j]
```

So the basic idea is: for arrays a and b, if an element is found in both of them, then I'll assign the score of that element in scoreA to scoreB. But the result is like this:

```
B is: 1.000000
A is: 1.000000
B is: 0.000000
A is: 0.500000
B is: 0.000000
A is: 0.333333
B is: 0.000000
A is: 0.250000
B is: 0.000000
A is: 0.200000
```

which means the line:

```
scoreB[i] = scoreA[j]
```

is not working properly? How can I resolve this?

Comment: IIUC, just do : `mask = a==b`; `scoreB[mask] = scoreA[mask]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is rather strange and it is better to make it as @Divakar mentioned. 
But anyway the straitforward problem is that `scoreA` and `scoreB` have different types: `float64` and `int64`.

make

```
scoreA = np.array([float(1) / (i + 1) for i in range(len(a))],dtype=float)
scoreB = np.array([0 for i in range(len(b))],dtype=float)
```

or some other dtype to make sure that all your scores have the same type.